# Is there anything close to automatic shuttle valve?

Tags: valves, pneumatic

I am building a pneumatic system that needs an automatic shuttle valve. That means if I apply air pressure on one of the inputs In1, it closes the other input In2 and creates a path between In1 and output. When there is no air pressure on In1, it closes In1 and creates path between In2 and output as shown in figure below. In2 is connected to a vacuum. Output is connected to a single acting cylinder without spring. Any recommendation of any other device that serves the purpose or even combination of devices, only non electrical devices.  Thank you [image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need if to be able to provide air from 1 or two. I think the easiest and cheapest way might be to use **two check valves and a T junction**.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. Problem I have is that I can control air pressure on/off at In1 but vacuum will always be there at In2. Also, check valves are operated on air pressure.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. A pilot operated valve to switch between air and vacuum.*

How it works:

- When pressure line is off out is connected to "vacuum".
- When pressure line is on the valve changes over and out is connected to "air". Vacuum line is shut off.

Description:

- 3-port, 2-way, pilot operated, spring return.

Make sure that the valve operates at the air pressure you've got.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, these kind of shuttle valves are not suitable for my application as they need air pressure from input inlets to have certain path open. My application has air pressure on one of the inputs and vacuum on other input.

Comment: @NHB, see the replacement answer.